# How to mock an Eloquent Model using Mockery?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying this:

```
$this->dsMock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'API\V1\DataSet');
$this->app->instance('API\V1\DataSet', $this->dsMock);
$this->dsMock->shouldReceive('isLocalData')->once()->andReturn(true);
```

Then, inside the class under test:

```
$test = DataSet::isLocalData($dataSetId);
```

However, the DataSet class is not being mocked.  It's still trying to access the database.  Why?

Comment: Theoretically this should work, but I suspect it's related to Laravels truly awful Facade system. Have you tried instantiating DataSet in `new DataSet()` after that instead of using the Facade? I can't remember off hand if you're allowed to do that or if you're forced to use the factory.

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is Laravel's unfortunate over use of Façade's (which are also factories). If `DataSet` was already instantiated using the Façade, it will keep returning the same class, you won't get a mocked version.

I can't remember off hand if you can instantiate your class without using the Façade in Laravel. You have to remember that when you call `DataSet` statically in the application, you're actually not referencing `API\V1\DataSet` but something else that manages it.